# What does failwithf do?

Tags: f#

I am unable to find information on *failwithf* within the [F# 4.0 spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf).

My apologies if this is a stupid question...

**But what is *failwithf*?**

**And why would I use it?**

Comment: `failwith "Hello"` generates an exception containing `Hello`. `failwithf "Hello %s" "There"` generates an exception containing `Hello There`. It's like `printf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the documentation [here](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-extratopleveloperators.html#failwithf).

```
failwithf : StringFormat<'T,'Result> -> 'T
```

It accepts a `StringFormat` much like the `printf` or `sprintf` which allows you to include typesafe string formatting, e.g.:

```
failwithf "Error Code %i" 55
```

Comment: Tomas urges against using this: https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/pull/225

Comment: @ScottNimrod There is now a compiler warning: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/46